# Not able to create valid nsurl

Tags: iphone, nsurl

I am trying to parse data from a xml web service but I am not able to get my url. Please check my code:

```
NSLog(@"log url: %@",url);
[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
[url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSLog(@"%@",url);

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSXMLParser *home_Parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
[home_Parser setDelegate:self];
[home_Parser parse];
[home_Parser release];
```

I am always getting URL as nil. The reason is my string url has space included. I have tried to replace it and escape it but it is not working. Following is the url that I am using

http://www.mydomain.com/radioListGenre.php?genre=Radiostations playing Rock
how can I remove this space. Is there any other technique the those I used above.

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: You need 4 spaces in front of *every line of code* in order to have it all format. The easiest way is to just select all of the code and click on the **{}** button, which will add 4 spaces to the beginning of every selected line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` and `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` operate on the string provided and **return a string**. You're not assigning the return value to anything so url isn't changing, the return value is just vanishing into space. You want something more like:

```
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

assuming url is a mutable string. Now url contains the modified version of url. Without the assignment it's effective the same as doing something like this:

```
a + 1;
```

instead of:

```
a = a + 1
```

Comment: yes i figured it out later... a silly mistake from my side.... thanks for the answer