# how to add empty space in string ios

Tags: ios, string, post

I have a string for post method. if string is like `"hello.."` than value is passing in post method. But if string is like `"hello world"` than its not taking to post method. If I use space in a string it's not working. please help me out.

```
- (void) constructURL
{
    NSMutableString* curl = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [curl appendString:@"XXXXX"];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?eventid=%@", eventID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&ForumID=%@", forumID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&parentPostID=%@", parentPostID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&userid=%@", userID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&PostContent=%@", postContent]];

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:curl];
}
```

Comment: use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding on string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to create valid nsurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637799/not-able-to-create-valid-nsurl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read these line, may be helpful to you. Extracted from apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/

```
Working with URLs
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
Returns a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

Declaration
SWIFT
func stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(_ encoding: UInt) -> String?
OBJECTIVE-C
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
Parameters
encoding    
The encoding to use for the returned string. If you are uncertain of the correct encoding you should use NSUTF8StringEncoding.
Return Value
A representation of the receiver using encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string. Returns nil if encoding cannot encode a particular character.

Discussion
It may be difficult to use this function to "clean up" unescaped or partially escaped URL strings where sequences are unpredictable. See CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes for more information.

Import Statement
import Foundation

Availability
Available in OS X v10.3 and later.
See Also
– stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
– stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
– stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
```

Your question answer is :

```
- (void) constructURL
{
    NSMutableString* curl = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [curl appendString:@"XXXXX"];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?eventid=%@", eventID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&ForumID=%@", forumID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&parentPostID=%@", parentPostID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&userid=%@", userID]];
    [curl appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&PostContent=%@", postContent]];
    curl = [curl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:curl];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to encode your string like this:

```
NSString* encodedString = [@"Hello World" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```